# Javascript app (with webpack ) not opening on heroku , " App boot timeout"

Tags: javascript, heroku, webpack

I'm currently trying to get my javascript+webpack app to deploy on Heroku.

Github link of the app [here](https://github.com/RaphaelPereira88/Travel-app).

It works fine locally, but I can't manage to deploy it on Heroku. I get an error message like: `App boot timeout`. See screenshot below:

Screenshot 1:

[image: screenshot 1]

Screenshot 2:

[image: screenshot 2]

Does anyone have an idea of how I can fix this?

ps: I tried Netlify, managed to have the app displayed but API calls didn't work because my API URL starting with http instead of https, but no way around that the API selected for this project doesn't on https :-( so that's why I'm trying to get this one to work on Heroku.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because your express code is binding to port 8081, while heroku likes to pass in it's own port when deploying express apps. That's why your error message is saying `Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch`. To fix this you need to pass in your port as a variable and bind to it.

**server.js**

```
const app = require("./index.js");
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 8081);

app.listen(app.get('port'), function () {
  console.log(`running on localhost: `, server.address().port);
});
```

Minimal code example [here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-node-js-app-to-heroku).

Comment: If this worked for you please accept as well! @Raphael Pereira